# Adding a gap between <ins> and <del> using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-content

I'm using the [htmldiff](https://github.com/myobie/htmldiff) gem to output a string of differences between two input values.

This output uses a combination of `<ins>` and `<del>` tags, along with the classes `.diffins`, `.diffmod` and `.diffdel` for styling purposes - so far so good, I can style all of this up without any problem.

Well, almost no problem, below is some sample output:

```
Here is some text that <del class="diffmod">will be</del><ins class="diffmod">has</ins> changed.
```

This is fine, for the most part, except there is no gap between the `<del>` and the `<ins>`, which is probably correct, but doesn't look right to me.

My problem is that I'm trying to use CSS to add a gap, but it isn't turning out as I'd like. This is what I have so far:

```css
.diffins {
  color: green;
}

.diffmod {
  color: blue;
}

del.diffmod + ins.diffmod::before {
  content: ' ';
}

.diffdel {
  color: red;
}
```

This adds a gap, but the underline style of the `<ins>` tag extends into the space created by the `::before`. As you can see here:

http://codepen.io/LimeBlast/pen/LVqBeo

I've tried adding `text-decoration: overline;`, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: padding-left: 5px; Maybe?

Comment: You don't want to use padding because you want the exact amount of space of a white space? I guess you can always edit the source code to add the space. Why not just kill the `text-decoration` on `ins` tag and just have the colour as blue? So it would not have under line at all

Comment: The html source code is provided by the gem and not something I'm able (nor want) to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without adjusting margins or padding by using the `::before` pseudo-element by giving it a `display` of `inline-block` and setting its content to `'\A0'` - which is a regular space, but `' '` alone doesn't appear to have any effect:

```css
body {
  font: 32px/40px sans-serif;
}

del.diffmod + ins.diffmod::before {
  content: '\A0';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
This is the <del class="diffmod">wrong</del><ins class="diffmod">perfect</ins> solution!
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqBaP).

Comment: I did toy with using a `margin-left`, and will probably have to, but this question is less about adding the gap, and more about overriding the values set by the `<ins>`. Plus, having pixel values for the gap is going to screw things up as soon as you start changing the font size, which is why I wanted to use `content`.

Comment: You could always set the margin size based on em units, which will scale with font sizes.

Comment: @SurrealDreams that would not work 20px font will not leave 20px space for white space

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
ins {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

this will kill the underline for the entire block but I don't see a real purpose of it since it is already in a different colour

Comment: I will admit, I'm no fan of using underline to highlight an insert, and much prefer something like italic (although, I'm not sure this is really any better) - but you might be right, the strike though is enough to show the deleted text, so the different colour does the rest.

Comment: I think the other answer will do if you really want to use the underline. But I honestly think the under line is an overkill. Once you get rid of the under line, the method you currently use is fine for the space

Answer (score 0):

Building on your existing code:

```
del.diffmod + ins.diffmod::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .25em; /* approx 1 character */
}
```

There is no actual content to display (and thus underline/strike) and the margin is in `em` and so reacts to font-size changes,

```css
.diffmod {
  color: blue;
}

del.diffmod + ins.diffmod::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
Here is some text that <del class="diffmod">will be</del><ins class="diffmod">has</ins> changed.
```